# how to get the auto-increment primary key of a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a small MySQL database of sellers where there is a table, in which each seller has an auto-increment primary key (and there is not any other unique key attribute). Now I want to retrieve each seller data from the php script

```
// Nothing wrong with this code
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM seller WHERE id= ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $ud);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

But.. to retrieve data with this query, I need to have the primary key ( i.e. autoincrement id of the seller ). How would I know what is the primary key of the record inserted?

Comment: do you want rows with latest id? last 10 new ids? all of sellers? You have to be more specific.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  If you have an `id` value and want to retrieve that record, then the query you're showing is exactly how you'd do that.  What isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for asking guys. Please see the edits.

Comment: @WijaySharma: What do you mean you can't "see the mysql table"?  Is your code not able to connect to the database?  Why not?  What does that have to do with IDs?  What's the *actual problem* taking place here?  Show the code you're using and explain what you're stuck on.  You need to clarify what the actual problem is before anybody can help you.

Comment: You are right @David. Please see the edits. I've described the problem in detail

Comment: Reason for the downvote please? I've described the question details and I think the problem is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert_id` attribute of the prepared statement saved me.
Now just after my insert statement I can get the last inserted primary key of the table-

```
$stmt->execute();
$sid = $stmt->insert_id;
```

This is equivalent to the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function in mysql. Make sure you use this in the same session, just after insertion of the table row. Otherwise, it returns a null set.

Answer (score 2):

You would get the ID from your own data.  For example, let's say you have a page where you list your Widget records.  The database query on that page might be something like:

```
SELECT id,name FROM widgets
```

Then you'd display the output in a loop.  Within this output, you might have a link such as:

```
echo '<a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a>";
```

Which would output something like:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=123">Edit</a>
```

When clicking that link, your browser would then go to `edit.php` with the query string data `id=123`.  So on *that* page you could get that query string value:

```
$_GET['id']
```

That value would be the ID of the specific record you want to display.  Use that as the parameter in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE id=?
```

Or, in your specific code, that's the value you'd pass to your function:

```
getUserData($_GET['id'])
```

However you design it, the point is that you get the IDs from your data.  You don't need to intuitively know what they are.

Answer (score 1):

1. As you are trying to retrieve seller data from MySQL server based on an auto_increment id attribute. I assume that initially you are unaware of any details inside the table beforehand.

   This can be handled using PHP by, initially retrieving all id's in the table, along with a partially identifying attribute like seller name and thereafter, fetching all details of the required seller using the selected id.

   ```
   if(!$con) die();
   function fetchId(){
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, name FROM seller");
       if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
               echo "ID: ".$row["id"]." NAME: ".$row["name"];
               retrieveData($row["id"]);
           }
       }
   }

   function retrieveData($id){
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seller WHERE id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id));
       if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
           $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
           print_r($row);
       }
   }
   mysqli_close($con);
   ```
2. Using auto_increment for an attribute like primary key is not a wrong approach when needing to retrieve data, but some partial rows containing the key are to be pre-fetched before the desired row can be individually accessed using it.